# CakePHP Relationship Save

Tags: php, cakephp, model-associations

I have the following structure which I need to be inserted in the Target table:

**Target** table:

```
target_id, client_crop_id, amount
```

**ClientCrop** table:

```
client_crop_id, client_id, crop_id
```

**Client** table:

```
client_id, client_name
```

**Crop** table:

```
crop_id, crop_name
```

My question is: At the moment of inserting a new Target, my view has the id of client and of crop, how will CakePHP know that the field `client_crop_id` at Target Model is the union of thus both quoted above? should I call a method at beforeSave() of Target to fetch the id of ClientCrop?

Thanks.

Comment: show the relations u have definesd

Answer (score 0):

You can add the desired fields in your view:

```
<?php

echo $this->Form->hidden('ClientCrop.cient_id', array('value' => $yourVar)); 
echo $this->Form->hidden('ClientCrop.crop_id', array('value' => $yourVar));

?>
```

But I do not recommend this approach due security. Try to set it directly in your controller action after post:

```
<?php

$this->request>data['ClientCrop']['client_id'] = $yourVar;
$this->request>data['ClientCrop']['crop_id'] = $yourVar;

?>
```

Then you should use the saveAssociated method.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array

Comment: While I totally approve the security tip, it's worth noticing that even if you leave ids in the view as hidden values, you should have the Security Component activated to avoid form tampering.

Comment: Ok, I got it, but, it will set Target.client_crop_id to respective ClientCrop by client_id and crop_id?

Comment: It will. CakePHP will detect the relationships from the models and save the related data.

Comment: Didn't worked as expected, it created a new ClientCrop, then Target.client_crop_id was set to the new. I need to get the ClientCrop that already exists, is that possible?

Comment: In your controller try to search for the ClientCrop through the ids that you have as parameters for the search conditions then assign it id to $this->request->data['ClientCrop']['id'] before save.